# Is there a script to Clear specific cells but not the formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[spreadsheet attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TXIfHRBNaYv5LQHs6HT8Tic6190Q3eh0iWJs350JilY/edit#gid=80617811)

The script below to clear fields works however, my formulas are also deleted.

I simply want to ensure the formulas are protected.
[image: image attached]

The formulas return information for the id entered into the cell (f16).

```
function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data Lookup');
  var rangesToClear = ['F6', "F8", "F10", "F12", "F14", "F16"];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
    var getCar = sheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
    sheet.getRange("F6").setValue(getCar);
    Logger.log(getCar)
    
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to categorize it correctly.

Comment: I think you're going about it in a funny way. You do NOT want to clear the field and keep the formula. What you actually want to do (I'm quite certain) is better refine the formula so that it returns valid data or nothing. Get the ID correct and you'll see their data. Type in the wrong ID and your code would set the cell contents to '' (an empty string). Least, that's the way I'd try to force MS EXCEL to provide the functionality of MS ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

I might be totally missing what you are trying to do, but I would leave the formulas and just remove the value in F16.  The formulas would still look for a blank cell and show the results of the blank ID - also blank.

Or change the formulas to IF(F16="","",yourformula)

Comment: I want to ensure that formulas remain if someone clears cells.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` formulas will error out when the search key is blank, because it will match *all* blank rows in Data. Replace them with `vlookup()` formulas like this:

`=iferror(vlookup(F16, { Data!F2:F, Data!A2:A }, 2, false))`

Use **Data > Protected sheets and ranges** to protect the range `F6:G14`.

In your script, only clear cell `F16`, and leave other cells untouched.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modified script

```js
function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data Lookup');
  var rangesToClear = ["F14", "F16"];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}
```

One change made here was that values were removed `rangesToClear` array. Previously it was:

```js
var rangesToClear = ['F6', "F8", "F10", "F12", "F14", "F16"];
```

And now its:

```js
var rangesToClear = ["F14", "F16"];
```

Which I believe corresponds to the "Phone" and "ID number" fields in your screen shot.

So now the script will only clear the ranges that don't have formulae.

The other change I made was to delete this:

```js
var getCar = sheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
sheet.getRange("F6").setValue(getCar);
Logger.log(getCar)
```

As this seems to fetch a value from `D6` which in you example is just the lable "Date:" (I don't know why the variable is called `getCar`), and then puts that in `F6`, which you seem to want to keep as a formula.

#### Reference

- [Range Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)